# Solve the inequality $(x^2-2\sqrt{a}\cdot x+1)(2^x+\lg a)<0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Solve the inequality $$(x^2-2\sqrt{a}\cdot x+1)(2^x+\lg a)<0$$

#### My work so far:

1) $a>0$

2) Let $f(x)=(x^2-2\sqrt{a}\cdot x+1)(2^x+\lg a)$.

$f(x)=0$ if and only if $x^2-2\sqrt{a}\cdot x+1=0$ or $2^x+\lg a=0$

$$x^2-2\sqrt{a}\cdot x+1=0$$
$$x_{1,2}=\sqrt a \pm \sqrt{a-1}$$
and $$2^x+\lg a=0$$
$$x=\log_2\lg\frac1a$$

Comment: What is $\lg a$? Do you mean $\log(a)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must do case work for $a$: 
1) $$a>1$$ then we have $$2^x+\lg(a)>0$$ and we have to solve $$x^2-2\sqrt{a}x+1<0$$  this is equivalent to
$$(x-\sqrt{a})^2<a-1$$ and further
$$|x-\sqrt{a}|<\sqrt{a-1}$$
can you proceed?
2)$$a=1$$ then we have $$(x^2-2x+1)<0$$ which is impossible.
3) the case $$0<a<1$$ is for you!

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ If $0<a<1$ then we have $x^2-2\sqrt{a}\cdot x+1>0$ for all real number $x$.

Then we must have

$$2^x+\log a<0\to 2^x<\log a^{-1}\to x<\log_2(\log a^{-1})$$

$2)$ If $a>1$ then we have $2^x+\log a>0$ for all real number $x$.

Then we must have

$$x^2-2\sqrt{a}\cdot x+1<0\to \sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a-1}<x<\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a-1}$$

$3)$ If $a=1$ then

$$(x^2-2x+1)(2)=2(x-1)^2\ge0$$

and then we have no solution.